# Circle detection in noisy images

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to detect circles in the following images. When the circles are occluded partially, the results are not good enough.

In this case the results are good.

[image: hole] [image: found hole]

The procedure that I am following is to fit ellipses in contours found by canny edges. In this case with the following contour is easy to estimate a ellipse or even a circle.

[image: the contour]

However, when the image contour has outliers,I can't fit a ellipse without taking into account those outliers.

[image]

To solve the problem I have decided to find a polynom to the curve using the approxPolyDP function, in order to place a real circle fitting the curve.However I don't know how the exclude the ouliers from the polynom generation.

Can anybody give me a hand?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why fit an ellipse and not a circle?

Comment: RANSAC fitting will help you to get better results for all the three cases. And you can decide upon the outliers and inliers that should satisfy some threshold so the contours to be a approximate ellipse or circle.

Comment: As wanted to find a quick method I thought that RANSAC fitting wouldn't be fast enough. However, I 've searched on the net and thanks to your advice I have found this. http://dvitonis.net/blog/2014/09/10/fitting-ellipse-ransac-python/ . Definetly I 'm going to give a try